# 6/6/20 12:51:18.676 PM cloudpaird[28573]: DEBUG cloudpaird: system does not support Continuity

Tags: icloud

I am running OS X 10.11.6.

I am seeing this warning in my Console system log every 10 seconds.

6/6/20 12:51:18.676 PM cloudpaird[28573]: DEBUG cloudpaird: system does not support Continuity

Any ideas on how to stop the service which is generating these messages?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Which is your Mac model? There is a post about `cloudpaird` here: https://github.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool/issues/207 which could be helpful on how to solve the underlying issue that triggers the error.

Comment: MacBook Pro from 2009; Model Identifier: MacBookPro5,3

Answer (score 1):

This post had the answer:

https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/12545/a-script-to-disable-handoff

disable_handoff.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#LocalHomes=$(/usr/bin/dscl . -list /Users NFSHomeDirectory | grep -v /var/ | grep -v /Library/ | awk '$2 ~ /^\// {print $2;}')

LocalHomes=$(ls -l /dev/console | awk '{ print $3 }')
for OneHome in $LocalHomes; do
    userName=$(/bin/echo $OneHome | awk -F "/" '{print $NF;}')
    sudo -u $userName defaults write $OneHome/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist ActivityAdvertisingAllowed -bool no
    sudo -u $userName defaults write $OneHome/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist ActivityReceivingAllowed -bool no
done
```